# OpenCV imwrite increases the size of png image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, compression, png

I am doing image manipulation on the png images. I have the following problem. After saving an  image with imwrite() function, the size of the image is increased. For example previously image is 847KB, after saving it becomes 1.20 MB. Here is a code. I just read an image and then save it, but the size is increased. I tried to set compression params but it doesn't help.

```
Mat image;
image = imread("5.png", -1); 

vector<int> compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
compression_params.push_back(9);
compression_params.push_back(0);

imwrite("output.png",image,compression_params);
```

What could be a problem? Any help please.
Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue and I guess it depends on the libraries used to compress the original image and the png library used by OpenCV.

Comment: what is -1 in imread? Why don't you just use imread("5.png")?

Comment: when setting second parameter to -1, imread will read png transparent image, otherwise it will not return alpha channel of the png image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PNG has several options that influence the compression: deflate compression level (0-9), deflate strategy (HUFFMAN/FILTERED), and the choice (or strategy for dynamically chosing) for the internal prediction error filter (AVERAGE, PAETH...). 
It seems OpenCV only lets you change the first one, and it hasn't a good default value for [the second](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/CV-IMWRITE-PNG-COMPRESSION-any-better-way-tp6099651p6486745.html). So, it seems you must live with that.

Update: looking into the [sources](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2dc5e245d0c0a644bd72f98e306fbd8b59aa91ba/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_png.cpp#L384), it seems that compression strategy setting has been added (after [complaints](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1452)), but it isn't [documented](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite). I wonder if that source is released. Try to set the option CV_IMWRITE_PNG_STRATEGY with Z_FILTERED and see what happens

See the linked source code for more details about the params.

Comment: So there is no solution for this problem with OpenCV?

Comment: You mean setting CV_IMWRITE_PNG_STRATEGY_FILTERED option? I write 
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_STRATEGY_FILTERED);
compression_params.push_back(9); but nothing happens.

Comment: I tried CV_IMWRITE_PNG_STRATEGY with Z_FILTERED. It decreases the size, but very little. For 1.20MB image I get 1.12MB

Answer (score 1):

@Karmar, It's been many years since your last edit.

I had similar confuse to yours in June, 2021. And I found out sth which might benefit others like us.

PNG files seem to have this thing called **mode**. Here, let's focus only on three modes: `RGB`, `P` and `L`.
To quickly check an image's mode, you can use Python:

```py
from PIL import Image
print(Image.open("5.png").mode)
```

Basically, when using `P` and `L` you are attributing `8 bits/pixel` while `RGB` uses `3*8 bits/pixel`.
For more detailed explanation, one can refer to this fine stackoverflow post: [What is the difference between images in 'P' and 'L' mode in PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307290/what-is-the-difference-between-images-in-p-and-l-mode-in-pil)

Now, when we use OpenCV to open a PNG file, what we get will be an array of three channels, regardless which mode that
file was saved into. Three channels with data type `uint8`, that means when we `imwrite` this array into a file, no matter
how hard you compress it, it will be hard to beat the original file if it was saved in `P` or `L` mode.

I guess @Karmar might have already had this question solved. For future readers, check the mode of your own `5.png`.

Comment: This question was posted 8 years ago. You are also using the `Python Imaging Library (PIL)` not `OpenCV`. Furthermore, this question and previous answers use the `C++` implementation of `OpenCV`, where `PIL` is obviously not available (at least not "natively"), so I'm not sure if your answer is still relevant.

Comment: If you read closely, you will find what I spent time writing makes sense. I am not using `PIL` to solve the problem; I am using it to quickly get to know what image mode is.

Comment: I am less familiar with `C++`, but I am almost sure that there exist libraries in `C++` to check image mode as well.

Comment: This is an excellent point. You can read about the PNG modes in [this other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52307290/7328782).