# How to set an individual pixel's color

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to loop through each pixel of an image, process that pixel, and set the pixel to a new color.

I've tried using Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image
picture = Image.open("image.png")

# Get the size of the image
width, height = picture.size

# Process every pixel
for x in range(0, width):
    for y in range(0, height):
        current_color = picture.getpixel( (x,y) )
        print(current_color)
        new_color = processPixel(current_color)
        picture.putpixel( (x,y), new_color)
```

But printing `current_color` just prints `0` for each pixel in the image

[Here](http://via.placeholder.com/640x360) is the picture I'm using

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use picture.size without parentheses.

As for the printed color, the picture you posted has ["P" mode in PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes), which is not "RGB" mode, hence the zeros you get.

Comment: That works, but `picture.getpixel((x,y))` still returns 0 (and  the picture isn't all black)

Comment: For me, your code works fine with an all-red png image. Paste your image online so that we can try it out.

Comment: Thanks... it was just something wrong with that picture and it seems like every other image works

Comment: Yeah, the picture you posted is apparently not in RGB mode.