# How to fix error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am opening a `png` file and then filling colour in that `png` file. My code is working for some `png` files but not for all.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image = Image.open("H:/baibhav/MPEG7dataset/apple_1.png")
width, height = image.size
center = (int(0.5 * width), int(0.5 * height))
yellow = (255, 255, 0, 255)
ImageDraw.floodfill(image, xy=center, value=yellow)
image.show()
```

I am expecting a figure as an output but it gives following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'

Comment: "for some png files" - examples? Which line exactly gives the error? If there more in the error message?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Since you mention that it works well for "some" and doesn't work well for "some", you have to provide the sample files or links for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply change

```
image = Image.open("H:/baibhav/MPEG7dataset/apple_1.png")
```

to

```
image = Image.open("H:/baibhav/MPEG7dataset/apple_1.png").convert("RGBA")
```

To know more, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307290/what-is-the-difference-between-images-in-p-and-l-mode-in-pil). `A` in `RGBA` is the `alpha` parameter. We use the alpha parameter when we want the color to get transparent. In simple words, it controls the opacity in an image.