# How to recognize an image file format using its contents?

Tags: image, image-processing, metadata, file-format

If a Image file is of format `.png` then it will contain ***‰PNG***, at the beginning of the file. (when read in *Text* mode)

If a Image file is of format `.bmp` then it will contain ***BM***, at the beginning of the file. (when read in *Text* mode)

I know that Image formats contain text (data) of certain size (bytes) in the beginning of the file, which is used as metadata of the Image file?

My Questions are:-

- Is this behavior same in all image file formats (or formats in general)?
- Could a image file (*of no extension*) be recognized just using this data?
- Is there information available on how this metadata is broken down? By that I mean, data at which position in the metadata has what meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this behavior same in all image file formats (or formats in
> general)?

For most of them, yes. There are some proprietary formats (e.g. for games) that might have very short or no metadata. Also, metadata might be in another file (e.g. animations together with XML metadata).

> Could a image file (of no extension) be recognized just using this
> data?

Yes. In fact, most image viewers will warn you if an image file has an incorrect extension and ask you if they should fix it.

On Unix systems, there's a [`file` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) that identifies files based on their metadata. There is a better tool specific for images called [identify (part of ImageMagick)](https://imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) that returns more detailed information on resolution, bitdepth, etc.

> Is there information available on how this metadata is broken down? By
> that I mean, data at which position in the metadata has what meaning?

There are books about (image) file formats and for most formats, this information is available in official specifications (e.g. [RFC 2083](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2083) for PNG). They list all of the (optional) file contents, describe the compressions and what a viewer/decoder/encoder can/must/should do with the data. A good starting point might be the [Wikipedia list of image file formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats).

Note that based on the examples you gave I suppose you opened files with a text editor which is not the ideal tool for that task. It's better to use a [hex-editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) for this. Text editors won't show most bytes (e.g. 255) by default and interprete others (e.g. tab or line feed). They might be good enough to see magic text strings like "BM" and "PNG", but with a hex editor, you can see both these text parts and their numerical representation - e.g. allowing you to extract image width and height. For this, some tool to convert [hexademical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) values to decimal is useful, most calculators can do this.

As an example, let's look at the beginning of a PNG file with a resolution of 6146 x 14293 in both a text editor and a hex editor:

[image: Comparison between hex and text editor]

You can see that the file is a PNG image in both of them, that's correct. But the marked part in the hex editor view will show the width and height of the image (matching the [PNG chunk specification of the "IHDR" part](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2083#section-4)) - `0x00001802` is 6146 in decimal, `0x000037D5` is 14293. There's no way to do this in the text editor.

Also note that even if you don't know an image format, you might be lucky with just guessing it's uncompressed data (this often works for some game image file formats, most notable Unity's "assets"). E.g. if you rename files to ".raw", the image viewer [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.net/) will give you a dialog (see the screenshot below) where you can guess width, height and bit depth of the image and see if the result looks good. This requires some experience in interpreting the outcome though, if width and bitdepth don't match, images will look like noise, warped, or have wrong colors.

[image: IrfanView screenshot]

This "image geometry guessing" can be improved/automated by trying different widths and computing the correlation coefficent between two lines. The tool [raw2tiff](http://www.libtiff.org/man/raw2tiff.1.html) can do this. Quote from the site:

> There is no magic, it is just a mathematical statistics, so it can be
> wrong in some cases. But for most ordinary images guessing method will
> work fine.

Comment: Nice Answer (+1). Btw can you please explain me why did you recommended to view images using a hex editor rather then a simple plain text one (like notepad)?

Comment: Thanks, added some more information on the text vs. hex editor part.

Comment: Thanks for the lovely explanation!! Just 1 more question, you stated "*There are some proprietary formats (e.g. for games) that might have very short or no metadata*", then how are those image's metadata (like size, bitdepth, color space etc) found? Like how is the image treated properly if no data regarding it is available beforehand?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is another case of "metadata in another file", e.g. all images might have standard dimensions of 1000 x 1000 and this information is located somewhere in the game code. Another special case example is the [Motion JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) format where a standard JPG header is used and this information is stripped from the JPGs inside the movie.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question!! I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Using Imagemagick, you can get that information (if available) for formats that Imagemagick can read from its "magick" data in the header file as follows:

```
convert image -format "%m\n" info:
```

For example:

```
convert lena.png -format "%m\n" info:
PNG

convert lena.jpg -format "%m\n" info:
JPEG

convert lena.pnm -format "%m\n" info:
PPM
```

Even if the suffix is removed, this still works:

```
convert lena_copy -format "%m\n" info:
PNG
```