# VOC2012: PIL Image.open converts PNG to 2d array

Tags: keras, deep-learning, python-imaging-library, python-imageio

I am working with VOC2012 dataset. The input image is in PNG format which has a shape of (375, 500, 4) when I use imageio to open the image. When I use PIL to open the image, then suddenly the shape becomes (500, 375). PNG images should have four dimensions on the last axis: r g b & alpha.[image: Here is a sample image]

The image is obviously colored image, so it should have 3 dimensions (height, width, depth). PIL seems to suggest that it only has two dimensions: width & height.

Can PNG images be represented by a 2d array? Please help! So lost at the moment. Thanks!

```
from PIL import Image
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
import os, imageio
import numpy as np

root_path = '/Users/johnson/Downloads/'

imageio_img = imageio.imread(
    os.path.join(root_path, '2009_003193.png')
)

# (375, 500, 4)
print(imageio_img.shape)
# [  0 128 192 224 255]
print(np.unique(imageio_img))


PIL_img = Image.open(
    os.path.join(root_path, '2009_003193.png')
)

# (500, 375)
print(PIL_img.size)

PIL_img_to_array = img_to_array(PIL_img)
# (375, 500, 1)
print(PIL_img_to_array.shape)
# [  0.   2. 255.]
print(np.unique(PIL_img_to_array))
```

---

It's also quite magical that PIL seems to know how VOC2012 labels the data. `PIL_image_to_array` has a unique value of `[0, 2, 255]`. Conveniently, 2 denotes bicycle in VOC2012. 0 means background and 255 probably means the yellowish boundary around the bicycle. But from the first code snippet, I never passed the pascal classes to PIL for conversion.

```
def pascal_classes():
  classes = {'aeroplane' : 1,  'bicycle'   : 2,  'bird'        : 3,  'boat'         : 4,
             'bottle'    : 5,  'bus'       : 6,  'car'         : 7,  'cat'          : 8,
             'chair'     : 9,  'cow'       : 10, 'diningtable' : 11, 'dog'          : 12,
             'horse'     : 13, 'motorbike' : 14, 'person'      : 15, 'potted-plant' : 16,
             'sheep'     : 17, 'sofa'      : 18, 'train'       : 19, 'tv/monitor'   : 20}

  return classes

def pascal_palette():
  palette = {(  0,   0,   0) : 0 ,
             (128,   0,   0) : 1 ,
             (  0, 128,   0) : 2 ,
             (128, 128,   0) : 3 ,
             (  0,   0, 128) : 4 ,
             (128,   0, 128) : 5 ,
             (  0, 128, 128) : 6 ,
             (128, 128, 128) : 7 ,
             ( 64,   0,   0) : 8 ,
             (192,   0,   0) : 9 ,
             ( 64, 128,   0) : 10,
             (192, 128,   0) : 11,
             ( 64,   0, 128) : 12,
             (192,   0, 128) : 13,
             ( 64, 128, 128) : 14,
             (192, 128, 128) : 15,
             (  0,  64,   0) : 16,
             (128,  64,   0) : 17,
             (  0, 192,   0) : 18,
             (128, 192,   0) : 19,
             (  0,  64, 128) : 20 }
```

Comment: Hi Mark, your answer has definitely solved my problem. I have ticked the green checkmark below the vote count buttons. Please let me know if I am not doing it correctly.

Thank you for answering my question! Helps a ton!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your image is palletised, not RGB. Each pixel is represented by an 8-bit index into a palette. You can see this by looking at `image.mode` which shows up as `P`.

If you want an RGB image, use:

```
rgb = Image.open('bike.png').convert('RGB')
```

If you want and RGBA image with transparency, use:

```
RGBA = Image.open('bike.png').convert('RGBA')
```

However, there is no useful information in the alpha channel, so that seems pointless.

---

Regarding the pascal palette, you can get that via PIL like this:

```
im = Image.open('bike.png')                                                                 

p = im.getpalette()

for i in range (256): 
    print(p[3*i:3*i+3])

[0, 0, 0]
[128, 0, 0]
[0, 128, 0]
[128, 128, 0]
[0, 0, 128]
[128, 0, 128]
[0, 128, 128]
[128, 128, 128]
[64, 0, 0]
[192, 0, 0]
[64, 128, 0]
[192, 128, 0]
[64, 0, 128]
[192, 0, 128]
[64, 128, 128]
[192, 128, 128]
[0, 64, 0]
[128, 64, 0]
[0, 192, 0]
[128, 192, 0]
[0, 64, 128]
[128, 64, 128]
[0, 192, 128]
[128, 192, 128]
[64, 64, 0]
[192, 64, 0]
[64, 192, 0]
[192, 192, 0]
[64, 64, 128]
[192, 64, 128]
[64, 192, 128]
[192, 192, 128]
[0, 0, 64]
[128, 0, 64]
[0, 128, 64]
[128, 128, 64]
[0, 0, 192]
[128, 0, 192]
[0, 128, 192]
[128, 128, 192]
[64, 0, 64]
[192, 0, 64]
[64, 128, 64]
[192, 128, 64]
[64, 0, 192]
[192, 0, 192]
[64, 128, 192]
[192, 128, 192]
[0, 64, 64]
[128, 64, 64]
[0, 192, 64]
[128, 192, 64]
[0, 64, 192]
[128, 64, 192]
[0, 192, 192]
[128, 192, 192]
[64, 64, 64]
[192, 64, 64]
[64, 192, 64]
[192, 192, 64]
[64, 64, 192]
[192, 64, 192]
[64, 192, 192]
[192, 192, 192]
[32, 0, 0]
[160, 0, 0]
[32, 128, 0]
[160, 128, 0]
[32, 0, 128]
[160, 0, 128]
[32, 128, 128]
[160, 128, 128]
[96, 0, 0]
[224, 0, 0]
[96, 128, 0]
[224, 128, 0]
[96, 0, 128]
[224, 0, 128]
[96, 128, 128]
[224, 128, 128]
[32, 64, 0]
[160, 64, 0]
[32, 192, 0]
[160, 192, 0]
[32, 64, 128]
[160, 64, 128]
[32, 192, 128]
[160, 192, 128]
[96, 64, 0]
[224, 64, 0]
[96, 192, 0]
[224, 192, 0]
[96, 64, 128]
[224, 64, 128]
[96, 192, 128]
[224, 192, 128]
[32, 0, 64]
[160, 0, 64]
[32, 128, 64]
[160, 128, 64]
[32, 0, 192]
[160, 0, 192]
[32, 128, 192]
[160, 128, 192]
[96, 0, 64]
[224, 0, 64]
[96, 128, 64]
[224, 128, 64]
[96, 0, 192]
[224, 0, 192]
[96, 128, 192]
[224, 128, 192]
[32, 64, 64]
[160, 64, 64]
[32, 192, 64]
[160, 192, 64]
[32, 64, 192]
[160, 64, 192]
[32, 192, 192]
[160, 192, 192]
[96, 64, 64]
[224, 64, 64]
[96, 192, 64]
[224, 192, 64]
[96, 64, 192]
[224, 64, 192]
[96, 192, 192]
[224, 192, 192]
[0, 32, 0]
[128, 32, 0]
[0, 160, 0]
[128, 160, 0]
[0, 32, 128]
[128, 32, 128]
[0, 160, 128]
[128, 160, 128]
[64, 32, 0]
[192, 32, 0]
[64, 160, 0]
[192, 160, 0]
[64, 32, 128]
[192, 32, 128]
[64, 160, 128]
[192, 160, 128]
[0, 96, 0]
[128, 96, 0]
[0, 224, 0]
[128, 224, 0]
[0, 96, 128]
[128, 96, 128]
[0, 224, 128]
[128, 224, 128]
[64, 96, 0]
[192, 96, 0]
[64, 224, 0]
[192, 224, 0]
[64, 96, 128]
[192, 96, 128]
[64, 224, 128]
[192, 224, 128]
[0, 32, 64]
[128, 32, 64]
[0, 160, 64]
[128, 160, 64]
[0, 32, 192]
[128, 32, 192]
[0, 160, 192]
[128, 160, 192]
[64, 32, 64]
[192, 32, 64]
[64, 160, 64]
[192, 160, 64]
[64, 32, 192]
[192, 32, 192]
[64, 160, 192]
[192, 160, 192]
[0, 96, 64]
[128, 96, 64]
[0, 224, 64]
[128, 224, 64]
[0, 96, 192]
[128, 96, 192]
[0, 224, 192]
[128, 224, 192]
[64, 96, 64]
[192, 96, 64]
[64, 224, 64]
[192, 224, 64]
[64, 96, 192]
[192, 96, 192]
[64, 224, 192]
[192, 224, 192]
[32, 32, 0]
[160, 32, 0]
[32, 160, 0]
[160, 160, 0]
[32, 32, 128]
[160, 32, 128]
[32, 160, 128]
[160, 160, 128]
[96, 32, 0]
[224, 32, 0]
[96, 160, 0]
[224, 160, 0]
[96, 32, 128]
[224, 32, 128]
[96, 160, 128]
[224, 160, 128]
[32, 96, 0]
[160, 96, 0]
[32, 224, 0]
[160, 224, 0]
[32, 96, 128]
[160, 96, 128]
[32, 224, 128]
[160, 224, 128]
[96, 96, 0]
[224, 96, 0]
[96, 224, 0]
[224, 224, 0]
[96, 96, 128]
[224, 96, 128]
[96, 224, 128]
[224, 224, 128]
[32, 32, 64]
[160, 32, 64]
[32, 160, 64]
[160, 160, 64]
[32, 32, 192]
[160, 32, 192]
[32, 160, 192]
[160, 160, 192]
[96, 32, 64]
[224, 32, 64]
[96, 160, 64]
[224, 160, 64]
[96, 32, 192]
[224, 32, 192]
[96, 160, 192]
[224, 160, 192]
[32, 96, 64]
[160, 96, 64]
[32, 224, 64]
[160, 224, 64]
[32, 96, 192]
[160, 96, 192]
[32, 224, 192]
[160, 224, 192]
[96, 96, 64]
[224, 96, 64]
[96, 224, 64]
[224, 224, 64]
[96, 96, 192]
[224, 96, 192]
[96, 224, 192]
[224, 224, 192]
```

---

Then, if you want to make the bicycle red, you can do:

```
# Load the image and make Numpy version
im = Image.open('bike.png') 
n = np.array(im)

# Make all pixels belonging to bike (2) into red (palette index 9)
n[n==2] = 9
# Make all pixels not red (9) into grey (palette index 7)
n[n!=9] = 7

# Convert back into PIL palettised image and re-apply original palette
r = Image.fromarray(n,mode='P') 
r.putpalette(im.getpalette()) 
r.save('result.png')
```

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, PIL, Pillow, image processing, palette, palette operations, masked image, mask, extract palette, apply palette.

Comment: Amazing Mark! I knew there is something special with the image itself. But I have no clue what's the word to describe it. Thank you so much! Now I understand.

Comment: I did a little explanation of palette images here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621

Comment: Does the default behavior of PIL palletisizing images differ from Windows to Mac? On my Windows machine image is read as an array of shape (280,280,3) (I use another dataset, not VOC2012), but when my colleague does it on Mac, she ends up with palletised image.

Comment: @hannarud Sorry, I have no experience of PIL under Windows. If you want to know what your images really are, use `exiftool` or **ImageMagick** `identify -verbose image.png`