# Use python to change the colours of an image to an specific palette

Tags: python, image, colors, python-imaging-library

I have images like this ones:

[image]

And I want to change its colour palette so they look like this one:

[image]

What I do is to reduce the amounts of colours in the image to a specific subset of 17. I need to be this specific 17 because I have to apply this process to around 700 images and I need consistency.

When I use gimp to archive this goal what I usually do is to create a colour palette based on an image and then *Image > Mode > Indexed* and choose the colour palette.

My plan was to do something similar using Pillow, but I haven't been able to find a successful way to do it.

Any suggestions? Should I try a different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: There are two solutions here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204807/2836621

Comment: maybe it can be converted with tools like [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/) and then you can use Python `os.system()` only to execute `imagemagick`.