# Change a particular range of colors to anothe color in CV2 or PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have an image as below

In this image, I want to convert yellow numbers to `BLACK` color & `RED` regions to gray. The already black & gray regions should not be changed.
How to I do that? Can anyone help?
I looked at several questions but i am not able to figure it out. Also, since the both yellow & red colors are not exactly the same but are in a range, i cannot to a direct replacement of the colors.
CV2 or PIL, both are OK.

If HSV values have to be used, please let me know how to figure the range. This questions has been asked & some answers are already there but I am not able to grasp them, so any additional guidance will be helpful

[image]

The output I am expecting is something like the pic below (created by painting the pixels in Gimp). Not exactly what you see, but you get the idea what I am looking for.

[image]

**Update**
The solution that I ended up using is as below. This made all the yellow letters as black & that was sufficient for me (i think,with the similar approach all the red areas could be made grey too)

```
img = Image.open('Testpic.jpg').convert('RGB')

roi = img.crop((652,125,697,295))
orig_color1 = (210,140,0)
orig_color2 = (210,210,210)

replacement_color = (4,4,4)
roi = roi.resize((288, 1014), Image.ANTIALIAS)
data = np.array(roi)
data[((data >= orig_color2)).all(axis = -1)] = (255,0,0)
data[((data >= orig_color1)).all(axis = -1)] = replacement_color
data[((data == (255,0,0))).all(axis = -1)] = (255,255,255)

img2 = Image.fromarray(data, mode='RGB')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your image is not the best quality and your results should improve if you can get a better input. I am just showing a technique with **ImageMagick** and may translate it into Python [wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.1/) later if anyone likes it - it shouldn't be too hard.

So, rather than selecting ranges in HSL colourspace, in this instance it is easier and probably better to remap the image to a specific palette since you only want to differentiate 4 colours. So, I made the following palette of 4 colours - a black, a grey, a yellow and a red like this:

```
magick xc:"gray(15)"  xc:"gray(178)" xc:"rgb(230,50,30)" xc:"rgb(230,190,90)"  +append palette.png
```

That makes this (much enlarged) 4x1 palette:

[image]

Then I remapped your image to the colours of that palette:

```
magick column.png +dither -remap palette.png intermediate.png
```

[image]

Then I replace all colours vaguely close to yellow with black, and all colours vaguely close to red with white:

```
magick intermediate.png -fill black -fuzz 30% -opaque yellow -fill white -opaque red result.png
```

[image]

Obviously change the `-fill white` to `-fill "gray(180)" if you want the background uniform, or add`-threshold 50%`:

[image]

---

If you don't want to use `wand` for some reason, you can use [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204807/2836621) to quantise to that specific 4-colour palette just the same.

Comment: Thanks for your effort on going through the problem & suggesting a solution. However, This did not serve my purpose only using cv2 & PIL only. I managed it another way, my solution updated in the question.