# How to preserve the color table for an indexed .png image

Tags: imagemagick, png, blender

I'm trying this command:

```
magick convert .\0.png +dither -colors 256 -remap .\allColors.bmp -define png:color-type='3' -define png:preserve-colormap out.png

convert: Valid palette required for paletted images `out.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1715.
```

[image: Image to convert]

[image: Palette image]

If I don't add the preserve colormap, it deletes all the unused colors, however I need to keep them so OpenRCT2 recognize the palette. I'm using ImageMagick from a python script in a blender file. If there is any alternative to creating an indexed png image with that specific color table, please inform me. Thanks.

Comment: `magick magick ...` is always wrong. `magick convert ...` is almost always wrong so don't use it unless you know you specifically need it. `./0.png` is pointlessly verbose, as is `./allColors.bmp`, just use `0.png`.

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57202093/2836621

Comment: magick magick was obviously a typo...