# Converting an Image to numpy array, then converting it immediately back to an image gives two different results

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

As the title states I'm converting my image to a numpy array then converting it right back. Here's my code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(os.path.join(no_black_border, png_files[0]))
img.show()

np_arr = np.asarray(img)
img1 = Image.fromarray(np_arr)
img1.show()
```

Here's my [before converting it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSzFt.png)
Here's my [after converting it back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaUFp.png)

Comment: Try to adjust 'mode' keyword in fromarray. Pil may choose wrong one. What is the shape and dtype of np_arr?

Comment: my np array is 200x200 both before and after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is not RGB, it is a palette image. That means it does not have a Red, a Green and a Blue value at every pixel location, instead it has a single 8-bit palette index at each location that PIL uses to know the colour. You lose the palette when you convert to Numpy array.

You have 2 choices.

Either convert your image to RGB when you open it and all 3 values will be carried across to Numpy:

```
# Load image and make RGB
im = Image.open(...).convert('RGB')

# Convert to Numpy array and process
numpyarray = np.array(im)
```

Or, do as you currently do, but re-appply the palette from the original image after converting back to PIL Image:

```
# Load image
im = Image.open()

# Convert to Numpy array
numpyarray = np.array(im)

... do Numpy stuff ...

# Convert back to PIL Image and re-apply original palette
r = Image.fromarray(numpyarray,mode='P') 
r.putpalette(im.getpalette())

# Optionally save
r.save('result.png')
```

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57010334/2836621) and accompanying comments.

Comment: oh wow thanks! Your first solution worked, but your second solution I was getting an error for, but thank you for your help either way! If you're curious my error for your second solution is "TypeError: cannot convert 'NoneType' object to bytes" on the line that you call "r.putpalette(im.getpalette())"