# PIL not always using 3 channels for PNG

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, channel

I have some images saved to PNG and unfortunately because of the encoding they always aren't 3 channel (this seems to be part of LodePNG).

When using PIL I will load images in and most will be (256,256,3) but ones where there isn't much color information end up being (256,256) (as far as I can tell this is a LodePNG thing). Since the majority of my images have 3 channels I would prefer to do that. But doing `img.convert('RGB')` does not accomplish the task.

Is there a way I can force PIL to open a png image to have 3 channels?

Note: I can open the images with preview and see that they are missing the third channel by looking in inspector. These files are also saved out with lodePNG.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("image.png").convert('RGB')
```

I've subsequently made a better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621).

Comment: I have to say I'm a little shocked that this works. Why is this different then `im = Image.open("image.png"); im = im.convert('RGB')`? Because that's what I was doing before and switching to a single line I have absolutely no issue anymore.