# Draw an image from array with PIL

Tags: python, arrays, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert an array to an image using the `Image.fromarray` in PIL but i can't seem to get the shape I'm looking for.
Here's my code:

```
def affichage(c, disp):
    for i in range(len(c)):
        for j in range(len(c)):
            if c[i][j]==0:
                disp[i][j]=[255,255,255]
            elif c[i][j]==1:
                disp[i][j]=[255,0,0]
            elif c[i][j]==2:
                disp[i][j]=[0,255,0]
            elif c[i][j]==3:
                disp[i][j]=[0,0,255]
    return disp

disp = affichage(c,disp)
img = Image.fromarray(disp, 'RGB')
img.save('affichage.png', 'png')
img.show()
```

I'm converting my array with value ranging from 0 to 3 int RGB colors but it display weird rows of color that don't output the same if i plot the array
Here is the output image:

`Using Image.fromarray`

[image: Using Image.fromarray]

`Using matplotlib to plot the array`

[image: Using matplotlib to plot the array]

How can I get the same output as matplotlib ?

Comment: Matplotlib is probably using a colormap. please show us the Matplotlib code you're using, too.

Comment: Please put back the `import` statements you have removed. Please show how you create `disp` and give some representative initialisation for `c`.

Comment: My matlotlib code for the colormap is:
`foret = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(["#8B4513", "blue","red","darkgreen"])
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(c,cmap=foret)`

Comment: I'm trying to display a forest with each cell representing a tree, c is the 'map' of this forest: No tree is 0 and the different stage of growth of a tree ranges from 1 (just planted) to 3 (harvestable). it is initialised randomly using `random.choices`
It is supposed to change each pass but with matplotlib i only managged to show the last state. I'm trying to convert it to an image but i can't pull it off.
disp is supposed to be an array giving each value a color in RGB mode.

Comment: If you only have a few colours (less than 256) you would be miles better off and miles faster with a palette image. Example here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/64682849/2836621 and explanation here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621

Comment: can we have 'c' = and 'disp' = ? just to try out your code ? and the way you used matplotlib to show c ?