# How to get pixel values of image in rgba format?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I'm trying to get the rgba values of the pixels of an image.

Google suggests I use code similar to this:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("C:/Stuff/image.png", "r")
px = list(im.getdata())
```

My problem is the data not always being in rgba format.

On some images it does return rgba

```
[(0, 0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255, 255), [...]
```

while on others it returns rgb

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255), [...]
```

and on some it returns whatever this is

```
[0, 0, 1, [...]
```

Is there a way to always get rgba returned?

Comment: Not all images have rgba data, so you would have to write a wrapper function to convert to whatever format you want.

Comment: You don't need a wrapper function, just use `im = Image.open("C:/Stuff/image.png", "r").convert("RGBA")`

Comment: Have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621