# PIL, numpy and matplotlib produce a plot that has vastly different colors from the original image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I am trying to plot some images using the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
if __name__ == "__main__":
    image2 = Image.open("Test Images/i3.png")
    image2 = np.asarray(image2)
    plt.imshow(image2, cmap="gray")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

But it plots something different from what I see in an image viewer:

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening?

The original image:

[image]

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you provided the original image.

Comment: Just added it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

**This is because that PNG has a palette, so pixel data are palette indices. `np.asarray` takes raw pixel data, the palette is not taken into account.**

**Use [`.get_palette() is not None`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpalette) on the PIL image object to detect if the image has a palette and [`.convert()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) to convert pixel data to "real" colors.**

---

This is a part of raw data, to get you an idea what it looks like. It includes a corner of the capital 'C' in the inscription:

[image: raw data]

The strange thing here that catches the eye is that while black is `0` (expectedly), white is for some reason `1` (rather than the expected `255`) and other colors are higher but still small, the highest value being `20`. Which hints that this is a palette thing.

When you `.imshow` this data, [it's normalized to `[0,1]`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html), mapping those 20 points, in order, to points equally apart from each other on the spectrum of the `Colormap` used.

[`png-parser`](https://github.com/Hedroed/png-parser) can show the palette data:

```
$ png-parser -d amdNt.png
<...>
Filename: amdNt.png | Size: 2925

(0)
IHDR:
Data size : 13
 - Width : 225
 - Height : 225
 - Bit depth : 8
 - Color type : Code = 3 ; Depth Allow = [1, 2, 4, 8] ; Each pixel is a palette index; a PLTE chunk must appear.
 - Compression method : 0
 - Filter method : 0
 - Interlace method : 0


(1)
PLTE:
Data size : 69
b'\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xfe\xfe\x01\x01\x01\xfd\xfd\xfd\xb4\xb4\xb4\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb6\xb6\xb6\xaf\xaf\xaf\x05\x05\x05\xfa\xfa\xfa\x10\x10\x10\xbb\xbb\xbb\x16\x16\x16\xb8\xb8\xb8\x0e\x0e\x0e\xf5\xf5\xf5\xaa\xaa\xaa\xc0\xc0\xc0\xf0\xf0\xf0\x19\x19\x19\xc4\xc4\xc4\xa6\xa6\xa6'
<...>
```

as well as the palette itself:

[image: palette]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621) in order to understand palletised (or indexed) images.

The short story is:

- if you want and expect a greyscale image with PIL, then you should always use:

  `im = Image.open("filename").convert('L')`

otherwise you may get a palette image.

- if you want and expect an RGB image with PIL, then you should use:

  `im = Image.open("filename").convert('RGB')`

If you don't do that, PIL may give you a palette image.

Furthermore, if you are opening images with PIL, it's generally a good idea to display them with PIL and save them with PIL, else you may run into issues of RGB/BGR ordering if you open with PIL and display with OpenCV, or with colormaps if you display them with `matplotlib`. I am not saying you cannot interoperate, I am just saying it is somewhat harder to mix libraries without issues of channel ordering and value ranges.