# PIL writing pixels in redscale rather than grayscale

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL to make pictures pixel by pixel. I notice that while I am specifying various shades of gray to my input, the output image is always in various shades of red. For example, I would assume that the following:

```
im = Image.new("RGB", (100, 100), "black")
im.putpixel((1,9), ImageColor.getcolor('rgb(255,255,255)', '1'))
im.putpixel((1,1), ImageColor.getcolor('rgb(55,55,55)', '1'))
im.save('test.png')
```

would create one gray pixel and one white pixel, however this creates two red pixels, with the "gray" pixel being a darker shade of red (see below). Why is this happening and how can I get the expected output of a gray and white pixel.

[image: Two red pixels, rather than a gray and white pixel]

Comment: Use `Image.new('L', (100, 100), 'black')`, check [PIL image mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307290/what-is-the-difference-between-images-in-p-and-l-mode-in-pil) for an explaining.

Comment: I will need to use rgb colors later, so single channel images will be insufficient

Comment: If you need `rgb` type color use only the `rgb` format, `ImageColor.getcolor('rgb(55,55,55)', 'RGB')`, `L` is more flexible and ill recomend using it if there is a mix of formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
im = Image.new("RGB",(100,100))
im.putpixel((1,9), (255,255,255))
im.putpixel((1,1), (55,55,55))
im.save("test.png")
```

Resulting Image:

[image]

Comment: This works for me as well. I do not know why setting the background color changes the output so drastically, and seemingly erroneously. If you have any insight into this let me know.

Comment: It still works if you set the background colour to black, I believe the issue is with the Imagecolor.getcolor part, although I don't know exactly as I usually define colours as rgb tuples.

Comment: I see. Yes, the issue was the style of the string/tuple I was using rather than the background color.