# What is the differrence between colormap and historam in the identify command output?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, imagemagick-identify

I use the identify command in the form below:

```
identify -verbose image.png
```

Part of the output is:

```
  Colors: 8
  Histogram:
     49602: ( 49, 51, 39) #313327 srgb(49,51,39)
     36492: ( 98,121,135) #627987 srgb(98,121,135)
     21728: ( 98,182,240) #62B6F0 srgb(98,182,240)
     39526: (121,131, 75) #79834B srgb(121,131,75)
     34298: (165,171,147) #A5AB93 srgb(165,171,147)
     29957: (185,200,226) #B9C8E2 srgb(185,200,226)
     18767: (210,185, 67) #D2B943 srgb(210,185,67)
     31774: (246, 69, 44) #F6452C srgb(246,69,44)
  Colormap entries: 9
  Colormap:
         0: (121,131, 75) #79834B srgb(121,131,75)
         1: ( 49, 51, 39) #313327 srgb(49,51,39)
         2: (210,185, 67) #D2B943 srgb(210,185,67)
         3: (165,171,147) #A5AB93 srgb(165,171,147)
         4: (185,200,226) #B9C8E2 srgb(185,200,226)
         5: ( 98,121,135) #627987 srgb(98,121,135)
         6: ( 98,182,240) #62B6F0 srgb(98,182,240)
         7: (246, 69, 44) #F6452C srgb(246,69,44)
         8: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF white
```

I see that the same colors as in Histogram plus white, but in a different order appear also in the colormap.

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line under `Histogram`:

```
49602: ( 49, 51, 39) #313327 srgb(49,51,39)
```

tells you that there are 49,602 pixels in the image with the colour `sRGB(49,51,39)`. So it is telling you the frequency of occurrence, or how often, each colour occurs.

---

The 9 lines under `Colormap:` are the **palette** of the image.

Let's look at the first line:

```
0: (121,131, 75) #79834B srgb(121,131,75)
```

That means that wherever the color `srgb(121,131,75)` occurs in the image, we only store the palette index `0` at that location, rather than the colour `121,131,75`.  That means we only use 1 byte to store a `0` instead of storing  3 bytes of RGB, which means we save 2/3 of the space. It is a *"LookUp Table"* or **palette**.

Palettes trade space for colour accuracy. In general, they are 1/3 of the size of the original image, but can normally only store 256 unique colours rather than the 16,777,216 colours of a conventional RGB image.

Just for fun, let's create this smooth greyscale gradient and some random noise as a conventional RGB888 image (which comes out at 75kB):

```
magick -size 40x600 gradient: \( xc: +noise random \) +append -rotate 90 PNG24:a.png
```

[image]

And now do the same thing, but oblige **ImageMagick** to create a palette image (which comes out at 25kB):

```
magick -size 40x600 gradient: \( xc: +noise random \) +append -rotate 90 PNG8:a.png
```

[image]

There is a longer explanation with example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621).