# How to retain the colors of a PNG image when converting back from an array

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, png, color-palette

Whenever I convert a PNG image to a np.array and then convert it back to a PNG I lose all the colors of the image. I would like to be able to retain the colors of the original PNG when I am converting it back from a np.array.

Original PNG Image

[image]

My code:

```
from PIL import Image    

im = Image.open('2007_000129.png')
im = np.array(im)

#augmenting image
im[0,0] = 1

im = Image.fromarray(im, mode = 'P')
```

Outputs a black and white version of the image

[image]

I also try using `getpalette` and `putpalette` but this does not work it just returns a NonType object.

```
im = Image.open('2007_000129.png')
pat = im.getpalette()
im = np.array(im)
im[0,0] = 1
im = Image.fromarray(im, mode = 'P')
im= im.putpalette(pat)
```

Comment: The error is this line `im= im.putpalette(pat)`: `putpalette` works *in place*, so don't write the result of this operation back to `im`. It's just `im.putpalette(pat)`. Using that fix, the second code works fine for me.

Comment: let me know if you still encounter problems

Comment: @HansHirse ah, rather simple fix. That works please feel free to post your solution if you would like me to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the second code provided, the error comes from this line:

```py
im= im.putpalette(pat)
```

If you refer to the [documentation of `Image.putpalette`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putpalette), you see that this function doesn't return any value, thus `Image.putpalette` is applied to the corresponding image directly. So, (re-)assigning the non-existent return value (which then is `None`) is not necessary – or, as seen here, erroneous.

So, the simple fix is just to use:

```py
im.putpalette(pat)
```

Using this change, the second code provided works as intended.

Answer (score 3):

Your image is using single channel color using palette. Try the code below. Also you can check more about this subject at [What is the difference between images in 'P' and 'L' mode in PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307290/what-is-the-difference-between-images-in-p-and-l-mode-in-pil)

```
from PIL import Image    
import numpy as np


im = Image.open('gsmur.png')
rgb = im.convert('RGB')
np_rgb = np.array(rgb)
p = im.convert('P')
np_p = np.array(p)

im = Image.fromarray(np_p, mode = 'P')
im.show()
im2 = Image.fromarray(np_rgb)
im2.show()
```

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the answer. Your solution is definitely correct, but I was looking for a solution that I did not have to convert the image to 'RGB'. I want to keep the image as a single channel while I am augmenting it as an array. Hans' comment fixed what I needed. If Hans doesn't leave an answer then I'll go ahead and confirm yours. thanks.