# PIL.Image.open only shows two colors while opening a PNG File

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am trying to open images (`.png`) using PIL. However, It only shows images only in two colours.

Original image (i.e. 3.24 MB). I reduced the size since system only allows us to upload below 2MB:

[image: Original image]

When I run `image = Image.open('path/image')` , it gives this:

[image]

when I run the same but with convert, `image = Image.open('path/image').convert('L')`
I get this:

[image]

Here is the way how i plot images:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(image)
ax.grid(False)
```

I have tried dozens of images. No change. I strongly guess the problem caused by the image channels. Function somehow reads the 3-channels as single-channel or the other way around. Any ideas how to fix???

---

Edit: So I got closer to the result i want. I convert the iamge into an array first. But it still is not enough.
[image]

here is the code:

```
image = Image.open(df['Path'][0])
image = np.asarray(image)
plt.imshow(image)
```

Comment: How are you plotting the image? With `image.show()`?

Comment: editted and added.

Comment: See here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621 and try `ax.imshow( ... cmap='gray')`

Comment: already tried it. It gives exactly the same results.

Comment: How does `np.histogram(image.getdata())` look like?

Comment: (array([ 160884,     117,     131,     141,       0,     106,     237,
             0,     113, 3073087]), array([  0. ,  25.5,  51. ,  76.5, 102. , 127.5, 153. , 178.5, 204. ,
       229.5, 255. ]))

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it. Transformed the image to array and read the values by cmap. Here is the full code and the result:

```
image = Image.open('/path/image')
image = np.asarray(image)
plt.imshow(np.abs(image), cmap = 'gray')
```

[image]