# How do I get a (R, G, B) output for a pixel with python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation

I'm trying to get the code to give me an output of the rgb value of a certain pixel

Input:

```
from PIL import Image 

img=Image.open(r"C:\img1.png")

pixelMap = img.load()
pixel = pixelMap[0,0]
print(pixel)
```

Output:`0`

Desired Output: `(0, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Your image is probably a palette image - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621). So change your code to this:

```
from PIL import Image 

# Load image - ensuring RGB not palette
img=Image.open(r"C:\img1.png").convert('RGB')

pixelMap = img.load()
pixel = pixelMap[0,0]
print(pixel)
```