# How to paste a semi-transparent image on top of a normal image and get the transparency PIL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

So I am trying to paste a transparent image on top of a normal image. But for some reason, the transparency is gone.

Is there a way to keep the transparency of the second image (the transparent one) on top of the first image (the normal one) without losing the transparency of the second image?

(I am new to PIL by the way)

```py
BG = Image.open("BGImage.png") # normal image, size is 1920x1080
BG = BG.convert("RGBA")
overlay = Image.open("OverlayImage.png") # transparent image, size is 1920x1080
overlay = overlay.convert("RGBA")

BG = Image.alpha_composite(BG, overlay) # I tried doing this but it didn't work

BG.save("NewImage.png")
```

Background Image:
[image: Background]

Overlay Image:
[image: Overlay]

What I got:
[image: What I got]

What I wanted (slight change in color):
[image: What I wanted]

Comment: Show what you got vs what you wanted

Comment: @MadPhysicist I did as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `paste` like this - after ensuring your image is not [palettised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621):

```
from PIL import Image

# Open background and foreground ensuring they are not palette images
bg = Image.open('bg.png').convert('RGB')
fg = Image.open('fg.png')

# Paste foreground onto background and save
bg.paste(fg,mask=fg)
bg.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: that didn't work, I got the same result I was getting before

Comment: Mmm, please share your images then and explain what you mean by *"didn't work"*. Thank you.

Comment: the result I got was the same as the last one, overlay not being semi-transparent

Comment: I managed to fix it, your answer helped me but I also realized that the image wasn't transparent for some reason (even though I saved it with the transparency). Anyways thx