# Why are pillow and numpy incorrectly converting my image sometimes (but not all of the time)?

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm making a program that involves converting pillow (PIL) images to numpy arrays and numpy arrays back to images. However, it is converting some (but not all) images back into a grainy, grayscale version of what they were before.

The relevant part of the code is:

```
from PIL import Image, fromarray
from numpy import asarray
im = Image.open("C:\\path\\to\\image")
pixels = asarray(im)
Image.fromarray(pixels).show()
```

This code is supposed to display the same image that it originally opened. It works for some images. For example, the following image of the flag of Andorra: [image: The flag of Andorra] . However, it doesn't work for other images, such as this image of the flag of Albania: [image: The flag of Albania]. Instead, it becomes a grainy black and white image:[image: Flag of Albania 2]. Having looked at the numpy arrays it generates, it looks like it is generating a number rather than an RGB tuple for each pixel in the the images where this doesn't work, but I can't figure out why. How would I make it so that the flag converts back and forth correctly?

Comment: It is explained here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Andorra flag is an RGB image, the Albania flag is a colormap image. PIL can convert colormap to RGB:

```
im = Image.open("C:\\path\\to\\image").convert('RGB')
print(im.mode)  # => now it prints always RGB, without convert it would print P for colormap images
```

You may find some documentation [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/handbook/concepts.html).