# Python Pillow - get brightness of black/gray/white pixel

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm asking this because both black and white (and all the grays in between) return `0` when their red, green, or blue values are called.

For example:

```py
photo = Image.open("C:\Users\USERNAME\Pictures\ThisImageIsBlackAndWhite.png")
pixelPhoto = photo.load()
redAmount = pixelPhoto[x,y][0]
print(redAmount)

# 0
```

It always returns a `0` no matter how bright/dark the actual pixel itself is.

Comment: How was `photo` defined? What is the output of `print(pixelPhoto[x, y]`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 added update to code snippet, output of ```print(pixelPhoto[x, y])``` was ```0```

Comment: Your image is a palette image, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621