# read, import and work with an image saved as .dat

Tags: python, image, pixel

I have an image save as pippo.dat , I want read it and work on it, the dimensions of the image are 368 x 600 pixel. How should I do?
I tried to use Numpy.readtxt but it doesn't work. I am a beginner.

Comment: How did you create the file?

Comment: `.dat` is a meaningless extension often used to mean just "data" in some custom format. You will need to know how the data was written in order to make sense of it.

Comment: file extensions are of little indication as to what the file actually contains. I could rename myzip.zip file to myzip.jpeg, doesn't magically make it into an image. What is actually inside this ".dat"?

Comment: Maybe share the file using Dropbox or Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the confusing file extension discussed in the comments; Numpy alone doesn't really support images as such, and trying to use `loadtxt` on one will just produce a mess if it even works at all.

What we can do is use another library like `Pillow` that *does* understand images, and create a Numpy array using that.
firstly you'll need to install Pillow `pip install Pillow`

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
# Open the image
image = Image.open('myimage.jpg')  # swap name as needed
print("Your image's size is", image.size)
# show the image in a window. You can delete this line if you like. 
image.show()
# convert it to a numpy array:
data = np.asarray(image)
```

And now `data` is a 3D numpy array of the image, the first 2 dimensions being X and Y pixels, and the 3rd being the colour values (`[R,G,B] or` [R,G,B,A] if its got an alpha/transparency channel. You can check with `image.mode`) (if you get a 'weird' palette or grayscale mode like P or L then read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/9311137 on converting/handling)