# read a single color png into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, png

I'm trying to load a single color PNG file into a numpy array. With most PNG files, the code below works fine. However, if the PNG file contains only a single color, the RGBA values of each pixel in the numpy array is `[0, 0, 0, 255]` which results in a black image.  In the case of the color "red", how can I access the correct RGBA values? e.g. `[255, 0, 0, 255]`

```
from PIL import image
import numpy as np

red_image = Image.open("red.png")
arr = np.asarray(red_image)
```

When calling `red_image.getBands()`, I expected to see a tuple of `("R",)` as per the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=getBands#PIL.Image.Image.getbands). Instead, I'm seeing `("P",)`. I have not idea yet what a "P" channel is but I think it's related to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'P' mean the PIL mode is in "palettised". More info here: [What is the difference between images in 'P' and 'L' mode in PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2601293).

converting from "P" to "RGBA" fixed my issue.

```
from PIL import image
import numpy as np

red_image = Image.open("red.png")
red_image = red_image.convert("RGBA") # added this line
arr = np.asarray(red_image)
```