# 2 Color PNG Images

Tags: image, png

PNG images can be RGB, which is 3 colors. Or they can be greyscale, which is 1 color.

Intuitively, it seems like there should be PNG images that are made out of two colors, and there is some way to convert from RGB to this two-color scale. Is there something well-known like this? And if so, how do you convert the images from RGB to this two-color scale.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably referring to palette images which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621) and Wikipedia describes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Pixel_format).

You didn't describe your environment where you want to convert between RGB and palette, so I'll show you with **ImageMagick** in Terminal on Linux, macOS and Windows:

```
magick InputRGBImage.png PNG8:PaletteOutputImage.png
```

Or, going the other way:

```
magick PaletteInputImage.png PNG24:OutputRGBimage.png
```

If you use PIL/Pillow, it is:

```
paletteImage = RGBImage.convert('P')
```

and

```
RGBImage = paletteImage.convert('RGB')
```