# PIL - Change multiple pixels values in a "mode P" image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, pixel

I would like to know how to change more than one pixel value in a `mode P` image with `PIL`.
In my case I have 3 pixels values: 0, 1 , 2. I would map them respectively to 255, 76, 124. 
I tried:

```
Image.open(my_image).point(lambda p: 255 if p==0 else (76 if p==1 else 124))
```

When I run the code above, I get an image with all black pixels.
 
Why?
 Sholud I use a different function rather than `point()`?

**Update:**
`.getpalette()` returns {0, 255}

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/71511757/2836621 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72729002/2836621

Comment: If you still don't have the answer you should post your image and your minimal, complete, runnable code.

Comment: @MarkSetchell This code works properly: `def show_mask(mask):
  return Image.open(mask).point(lambda p: 255 if p==0 else 0)`. I don't know why it does not  work with 3 colors substitution

Comment: As I said above, if you still don't have the answer, please post your image and minimal, complete, runnable code so that folks can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If all pixels in your image with the same value mapping to the same output value sounds fine, then `Image.point()` is definitely the right way to go.

Now why you're getting a black image depends on the color values defined in the palette. You can check the image's palette by calling `Image.getpalette()`. If your palette defines only 3 color values and anything beyond index 9 in the palette data is 0, then you should map your pixel data in that range, anything other than that will map to the default black.

If you want to use other color values than these defined in your palette, then consider converting to other color modes before calling `Image.point()`:

```
Image.open(my_image).convert('L').point(lambda p: 255 if p==0 else 76 if p==1 else 124)
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested (without `convert(L)`), but I still get a completely black image.