# How to edit pixels via PIL with a 1D array [0:255]

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Using the following code, PIL easily returns an array of single pixel values from an image. Not sure what the term for it is; but instead of a 3d array (RGB), it simplifies each pixel into one of 256 values.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(image_path, 'r')
pixel_values = list(im.getdata())
```

The question is, **how can I edit pixels on an image with this same method?** I believe the default arg for the `putpixel` method expects a 3d array (RGB), and if I only give one value; it only ranges over shades of black.

```
im.putpixel((x, y), value)
im.show()
```

I would like to be able to substitute integers (0-255) in for `value` and have access to the wider spectrum of discrete colors.

Is this possible? Seems like it should already be a built in method.

Comment: It's variously called a *"palette image"*, or *"indexed image"* https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for noting the terminology. Though I don't see info on that thread for updating pixels using palette mode, only reading them.

Comment: As with your other question, you didn't make it easy for folks to help you. So we can't see your image, or its type, or how many palette entries it has.