# Cannot Change the Pixel Values of GIF Image

Tags: python, pycharm, gif, image-segmentation, bit-depth

I'm trying to mask some masks for the segmentation task. The current mask I have is GIF format and has a bit depth of 8. The value of the pixels is 0 and 1. As shown below:

[image]

[image]

I get this via debugging using:

```
output = Image.open("./mask.gif")
output = np.array(output)
```

Note that I don't know why the pixel value of 1 is so bright as the value range seems to be 0-255 for an 8-bit image and it should be quite dark.

[image]

Now I want to do the triple segmentation thus I need to process the pixel values into 0, 1, and 2. I use these codes to process some of the masks with values of only 0 and 1 to 1 and 2:

```
dir = './'

mask = Image.open("./mask.gif")
mask = np.array(mask)

print(mask[250][200])

for i in range(mask.shape[0]):
    for j in range(mask.shape[1]):

        if mask[i][j].all() == 1:
            mask[i][j] = 2

print(mask[250][200])

mask = Image.fromarray(mask)  
mask.save('mask2.gif')
```

It seems to work because the print shows the right result. However, after I read the saved GIF again and I find that the pixel value also only is 0 or 1.

[image]

I'm quite confused why an 8-bit image performs like this. May I know where I'm wrong?

Comment: Have a read here.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ok, let me check it later, thanks!