# Why is Pillow's Image.getpixel raising a "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object"?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am looking for a solution for

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Here is the code

```
from PIL import Image
source = Image.open("download.png")
width, height = source.size
result = Image.new("RGBA", (width,height))
for w in range(width):
   for h in range(height):
       r,g,b = source.getpixel((w, h))
       gray = int(r * 0.212 + g * 0.715 + b * 0.0746)
       result.putpixel((w, h), (gray, gray, gray, 255))
result.save("gray_house.png")
```

and here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "/Volumes/PYTHON/pillow example/fds.py", line 7, in <module>
  r,g,b = source.getpixel((w, h))
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Comment: edit the"if you find the solution, thank you" I thought it was outside the code fence so that isn't the error code

Comment: Is your image an RGB image, not a greyscale one?

Comment: You can click on the **Edit** button at the bottom of the post to [edit] your own post.

Comment: Your image is almost certainly a palette image, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621

Answer (score 1):

`getpixel()` has worked just fine and returned **a number**, the problem happened when you tried to assign one number to three variables ("unpack" it as if it was a list or a tuple).  You cannot rely on [`Image.getpixel()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpixel) returning `(r, g, b)` tuple for every image.  For example, with another PNG image you could have stumbled upon *"ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)"* (since many PNG images contain alpha channel data, too, thus yielding 4-item tuple `(r, g, b, a)`).

So, assign pixel data to a variable and check its type and length (if it's a tuple).  Or even better, use [`Image.getbands()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getbands) to get this information explicitly and proceed accordingly.

#### But why?

##### (an update)

We haven't seen your actual image, but it's unlikely to be greyscale, since you try to convert it to greyscale.  Instead it's likely to be *palettised*.  For more info see an excellent explanation
["What is the difference between images in 'P' and 'L' mode in PIL?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/9288580) (suggested by [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell))