# Using a distance function on an image to compare colors of each pixel and to change their color

Tags: python, image, colors

```
for y in range(image.getHeight()):
    for x in range(image.getWidth()):

def GetDistance(tuple1,tuple2):
    tuple1=(r,g,b)
    tuple2=(r2,g2,b2)
    import math
    math.sqrt(((r-r2)**2)+((g-g2)**2)+((b-b2)**2))
    return
```

I am trying to compare to pixel colors in an image. For the colors that are the closest to red I want to change to blue, the closest to blue I want to change to green, and the color in the image that are closest to green I want to change to red. How can I get the color pixels I am looking for in the image?

Comment: Please click [edit] and add a sample image and the expected output/result. Do you mean your output image will consist purely of 3 perfect colours - red, green and blue?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't approach this using `for` loops as they are slow, inefficient and error-prone in Python. However, I have implemented it with `for` loops so it matches your way of thinking and is easier to understand. If you look through some of my other answers you will find better ways of doing it.

I note a couple of things:

- you don't need to take the square root of the distances, you can simply compare the squared distances. If `a**2 > b**2`, it follows `a>b`, as long as there are no negatives involved which will always be the case here because both `a` and `b` are themselves the sums of squares
- as your output image will consist of just 3 colours, it can best be stored as a palette image - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621). So I did that.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

def closestColour(px):
    """Returns palette index for whichever colour (out of R, G and B) is nearest"""
    # Unpack the tuple into its constituent parts
    R, G, B = thispx

    # Calculate distance to solid Red, solid Green and solid Blue corners of colour cube
    # No need for sqrt(), if a**2 < b**2 we know a>b as long as no negative numbers are involved and there aren't because a amd b are sums of squares
    RdistSquared = (255-R)**2 + G**2       + B**2
    GdistSquared = R**2       + (255-G)**2 + B**2
    BdistSquared = R**2       + G**2       + (255-B)**2

    # Find index of minimum value in list
    values = [RdistSquared, GdistSquared, BdistSquared]
    mi = values.index(min(values))

    # Map red to blue, blue to green and green to red
    lkup = [2, 0, 1]
    return lkup[mi]


# Open input image and load pixels
im = Image.open('billiards.jpg')
px = im.load()

# List of output pixels
outpx = []
for y in range(im.height):
    for x in range(im.width):
        thispx = px[x,y]
        outpx.append(closestColour(thispx))

# Create palettised output image, same size as original
out = Image.new('P', im.size)

# Stuff in the list of pixels
out.putdata(outpx) 

# Stuff in the palette, index 0 = Red, index 1 = Green, index 2 = Blue
out.putpalette([255,0,0, 0,255,0, 0,0,255])

out.save('result.png')
```

That transforms this:

[image]

Photo by [Sandesh Sharma](https://unsplash.com/@sandeshsharma27?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText) on [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/s/photos/billiards?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText)

into this:

[image]

---

By the way, there is no real need to write any Python to do this, you can just do it in the Terminal with **ImageMagick**, like this:

```
# Make a small palette of the colours we want to remap to
magick xc:red xc:lime xc:blue +append PNG8:rgb-palette.png
```

[image]

```
# Remap to the new palette, without dithering and then re-order colour channels
magick billiards.jpg +dither -remap rgb-palette.png -channel-fx ',1,2,0' result.png
```