# Change color of every 2-nd element on x axis and every 3-rd element on y-axis to black

Tags: python, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I don't know what's wrong and why nothing worked for me. The picture is 500x500.

I tried using arrays and loops but It didn't work out. My code

```
from PIL import Image

picture_resized = picture.resize( (500,500) )

im = np.array(Image.open('Lenna.png').convert('RGB'))

Image.fromarray(im).save('result.png')

im[0::2,0::2] = [0,0,0]
im[0::3,0::3] = [0,0,0]

%matplotlib notebook
plt.imshow(picture_resized)
```

Comment: Please clarify what did not work out for you. The lines `im[0::2,0::2] = [0,0,0]` and `im[0::3,0::3] = [0,0,0]` seem for me to do exactly what you want. Your provided code however saves an image before you do the desired processing and is showing (`plt.imshow`) `picture_resized`, which is also not processed for having black pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You're close! This should do what you want:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load image and make into Numpy array
im = np.array(Image.open('artistic-swirl.jpg'))

# Make every second element on x-axis black
im[:, 0::2] = [0,0,0]

# Make every third element on y-axis black
im[::3, :] = [0,0,0]
```

**Note**: You should read a colon (`:`) as meaning *"all columns"* or *"all rows"* depending on whether it is specified for the first or second axis.

Turns this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

If you are using Jupyter, based off your question, you'll need to add something like this at the end to actually display the result.

```
%matplotlib notebook
plt.imshow(im)
```

Or, if you want to save a PNG with PIL, you can use:

```
im.save('result.png')
```

Comment: This code below did the job, but it opens up as an image from the pc but it doesnt load below the code, it shouldn't manually open me the image I got from that code,that's weird.                                                                                                                         import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = np.array(Image.open('Lenna.png'))


im[:, 0::2] = [0,0,0]


im[::3, :] = [0,0,0]

Image.fromarray(im).show ('result.png')

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry. It's hard to read code in comments. Also, there is no punctuation. Maybe any issues are caused by using a PNG which may be indexed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621 Try adding `.convert('RGB')` to the end of the line in which you do `Image.open()`.  I didn't need that as I used a JPEG.

Comment: I just want my image to show up under my code the print command didnt work, I dont need to open it up just to show up underneath my code, like 2 images you just uploaded above. The code did the work but I need my image to show up.

Comment: I'm still unsure what the issue is, but have updated my answer near the end.