# How does a single-number value work for coloring?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, png

I've got the following code (Python 3.10.7)

```
from PIL import Image

IMG_W = 600
IMG_H = 600
image = Image.open(r".\example-hat.png")
image = image.resize((IMG_W, IMG_H))
imgColors = Image.Image.getcolors(image,360000)
imgColors.sort(reverse=True)
print(imgColors)
```

The input image is this:

[image: Black and White Image]

The output I am getting is this:

`[(240408, 0), (119268, 1), (72, 2), (36, 9), (36, 8), (36, 7), (36, 6), (36, 5), (36, 4), (36, 3)]`

What I was expecting to get is RGB(A) values for the color, like `[(240408, (0,0,0)), (119268, (255,255,255)), ...]`, which I get for other PNG images.

So, how does this single-number value work for an image?  Given the image is mainly #000 and #FFF, I would guess values 0 and 1 coordinate to those, meaning the values > 1 would have to be some type of grey?  But how does that work, exactly?  Like, what would the hex/RGB equivalent of "9" be?

Comment: Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell `image.convert('RGB')` seems to work.  Not sure why my searches never turned up anything suggesting that.