# Convert Image to array and array to image using python, does the array contain metadata or other info?

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, metadata

Sorry for my english but it's not my first language.

I would like to create a program that:

- Transform a jpeg or png image into an array (very important: I would like an array composed only of the values that the pixels of the image have and not metadata or other information. Where I can select each specific pixel of the image).
- Save this array in a txt file.
- Transform this array composed of only the pixel values of the image back into jpg or png image and save it in a file.

Requests:

- Is the array I created with the program I wrote composed only of the pixel values of the image? is there also metadata or other information?
- Is this a valid way to remove metadata from an image?
- Is this a valid way to create the array representing that image pixel by pixel?
- Is this a valid way to convert png images to jpeg or jpeg to png?

Thank you!

This is the program I created, any opinion?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import sys

img_data = Image.open("imagea.jpeg")
img_arr = np.array(img_data)
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

print(img_arr.shape)

new_img = Image.fromarray(img_arr)
new_img.save("imageb.jpeg")

print("Image saved!")

file = open("file1.txt", "w+")
content = str(img_arr)
file.write(content)
file.close()

print("Finished!")
```

Comment: Your idea here is to convert jp(e)g to png without preserving metadata? so yes, because that does not happen anyways using `img.save('your_name.png', 'PNG')` PIL method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading an image and converting it to a Numpy array is a perfectly legitimate way of discarding all metadata including:

- EXIF data, copyright data,
- IPTC and XMP data,
- ICC colour profile data

You can tell it's all gone by thinking about the Numpy array you hold and its dimensions and data type.

---

Note that you need to be careful with PNG [palette](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621) images and images with an alpha channel.

---

Note that you can achieve this more simply on the command-line with **ImageMagick** using:

```
magick mogrify -strip IMAGE.JPG
```

Or with `exiftool`.

---

Note that you can achieve this by using a format that doesn't support metadata, such as [NetPBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm), with extension `.ppm` e.g.:

```
magick INPUT.JPG -strip -compress none RESULT.PPM    # gives P3/plain ASCII file
magick INPUT.JPG -strip RESULT.PPM  # gives P6/binary file
```

You can also read/write PPM files with **PIL**.

Comment: The .ppm image format completely solved the problem for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I did what you did using C with the libjpeg-turbo library. Does the image lose quality when switching from jpg to ppm? I used djpeg jpegfile.jpg imagefile.ppn .

Comment: @andreo No, it is the encoding into JPEG that discards colour and quality, not the decoding from JPEG. If any information was lost it was when the JPEG was created.