# Do I lose quality if I decompress a JPEG file into a ppm using libjpeg-turbo C library?

Tags: c, image, jpeg, ppm, libjpeg-turbo

I was trying to turn a jpg photo into a pixel map. I discovered that I can do it with the C library libjpeg-turbo by transforming the jpg photo into ppm. With djpeg jpegfile.jpg imagefile.ppn.

Does the file imagefile.ppn lose quality compared to jpegfile.jpg? Why?

I'm more interested in a technical answer. I'm studying a bit of programming and image formats and I have this doubt, I read the official libjpeg-turbo website but I couldn't find any information about it. By doing the opposite I know you lose quality and the site explains it (from ppn to jpg).

Comment: PPM is a bitmap format.  There is no *additional* image degradation from converting your JPEG to PPM, but a degradation relative to the original image -- whether on a camera's sensor or in a file -- is already baked into the JPEG.

Comment: Any loss of quality occurs when compressing a raw image into a `.jpg` (based on the quality metric specified when compressing). I can't speak to the specifics of `libjpeg-turbo`, but any decent jpeg _decoder_ should faithfully _decompress_ the JPEG image (it is a "slave" to the "instructions" in the JPEG file). Converting that raw/decompressed image into PPM should not introduce any further distortion. It might be better to decompress the JPEG image with _various_ decoders (e.g. ImageMagic `convert`, `ffmpeg`, etc.) and compare those against `libjpeg-turbo` decompression.

Comment: The "true" art is in JPEG _compression_. A given compressor has to select compression methods based on its own heuristics. These can vary.

Comment: I agree with both, but if I have a jpg image and I want to edit it there are no alternatives. Unfortunately I can't do anything about the loss of quality due to the first jpg compression. If I had any lossless format of that image I would use that.

Comment: @andreo Your question only talks about quality and doesn't mention metadata. The answers therefore focus on quality, yet in your comments it seems like the answers haven't answered your question. I'm confused.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No no, you answered my question perfectly. I just had an off topic curiosity.

Comment: @andreo Aha, ok, that's nice. I think that people in general are more keen on answering questions regarding other, maybe remotely related, questions in comments once an answer to the actual question has been accepted and if the new question isn't worthy of a being posted as a separate question - if they know the answer that is. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form of a digital image that is captured by a digital camera or can be displayed on a screen or printed on paper is a raster (regular 2D array) of digitized pixel colors.  This is sometimes called a "bitmap".

So,

> Does the file imagefile.ppn lose quality compared to jpegfile.jpg?

It's a bit complicated, but the simple answer is no, not if the image converter does its job correctly.

There is a "quality" factor associated with JPEG because it does not represent bitmaps directly. It employs a *lossy* representation that reduces the space required to represent images.  That algorithm has an adjustable tradeoff between image size and lossiness that is characterized by what has come to be known as a quality factor: lower quality means smaller and lossier.  That effect is incurred when the original image, whether on the image sensor of a digital camera, in computer memory, or in a file, is converted to JPEG format.  It is then baked into that JPEG -- it represents a slightly different image than the original, because some information has been lost.

To display a JPEG on a screen or convert it to a different format or otherwise edit it, it needs to be converted back to a bitmap.  The result will not exactly match the original, but if the reconstruction is done correctly then  a given JPEG should yield the same bitmap every time.  There need not be any additional data loss at this step.

PPM is different.  It represents images directly in the form of bitmaps. PPM's bitmaps have three color channels supporting up to 16-bit depth each, which is more than your monitor does, very likely more than the images you are working with do, and more than your eyes can resolve.  It can directly represent the bitmap produced by decompressing a JPEG without any loss of detail.

It gets more complicated, though, when you bring color spaces, non-linearity, and similar considerations into it.  These are not what JPEG's quality factor is about, but they do constitute another image-representation dimension that makes room for a PPM (or other image file) to be interpreted differently than the original image.  JPEG's native color space is YCbCr, whereas PPM's is a calibrated, gamma-corrected RGB color space.  Conversion is necessary from one to the other, and this can introduce slight color distortions, especially with narrow color channels.

Note also that there are other image formats available.  Many employ one or another form of *lossless* compression to reduce images' storage sizes, which can be a distinct advantage over PPM.  GIF was at one time a major format, but  it has somewhat fallen out of favor.  PNG seems to be winning the bitmap wars at the moment.  It is a more complex format than PPM, but very good, with built-in support for lossless compression.

Comment: I don't want to use an uncompressed format to store previously-lossy-compressed data. In general I'm trying to create a small image editor in C to understand what happens in detail when I edit an image with GIMP. IMAGE-->decompress-->bitmap-->edit-->bitmap-->compress-->IMAGE this is the process.

Comment: Now I know the an image doesn't lose quality when I switch from JPG to PPM. I don't understand how GIMP handles metadata... Does it transcribe them into the final image? Does it ignore them? I would like to create an editor that returns images that always have the same metadata and raw data template. For example, with GIMP if I deactivate all metadata when I export an image it creates a final image that always has those 10 fundamental metadata. Does this mean that it always adds the same metadata to the final image and ignores all the metadata of the initial image?

Comment: @andreo, I anticipate that GIMP preserves metadata to the extent it can do.  Image formats have different provisions for metadata, so image editing programs are limited in what they can do in that area.  Details of GIMP's particular behavior and capabilities are off-topic here, however.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, PNG being a lossless image format means that if I want to decompress a PNG image into a PPM image and then recompress the PPM image into a PNG image with the same software I should obtain two PNG files identical right?

Comment: @andreo, that is a question of the software involved.  I would generally expect such a round-trip conversion to preserve the bitmap data exactly, but PNG contains a lot more than that, whereas PPM does not. Also, PNG has provides some options allowing for variations in the way the bitmap data are stored.  Overall, no, I wouldn't particularly expect the final PNG to be byte-for-byte identical to the original one.

Comment: Shouldn't the raw image be the same in both the initial PNG image and the PPM file as well as the final PNG?

Comment: I did a test with GIMP. First I exported a JPG file to PNG. Then I exported the same JPG file to PPM and then I exported the PPM to PNG. The two files have exactly the same size and if I check if there is any difference between them with the diff command it tells me that they are identical.

Answer (score 4):

You will not lose fidelity when converting to PPM.  Why? It's a lossless format.

It's also an uncompressed format. I would highly recommend using something else, though, otherwise you're being extremely inefficient with your disk space.

Why is particularly inefficient?  Because you've already lost your fidelity through the JPEG compression.  You are not gaining any fidelity back by storing in an uncompressed format.  You are just faithfully storing your image after the fidelity has already been lost.

Comment: Compression is not the essential determinant here.  For example, PNG can be and typically is compressed, but that does not reduce fidelity.

Comment: Yeah, but PPM is not lossless-compressed like PNG can be.  It is simply uncompressed.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Then rather than _"Why? They're uncompressed."_ you could say _"Why? Because it's a lossless format."_.

Comment: This answer misses the point. The point is that the quality was lost when the JPEG was created.

Comment: @MarkSetchell _"you've already lost your fidelity through the JPEG compression"_ does mention that though

Comment: I agree, it does mention that... but it implies the fact that PPMs are uncompressed is crucial, when it isn't.

Comment: I was simply encouraging the OP to not use an uncompressed format to store previously-lossy-compressed data, because it gains you nothing.

Comment: Also, the fact that PPMs are uncompressed is precisely why you don't lose any more fidelity.

Comment: It does gain something, but the OP didn't state it in this question. I believe the OP has a reason for wanting to store the data in PPM format because that format is (largely) incapable of storing any metadata - see comment here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75345600/2836621

Comment: There are better ways of stripping metadata from files...

Comment: I agree. I mentioned some in the linked answer.

Comment: I don't want to use an uncompressed format to store previously-lossy-compressed data. In general I'm trying to create a small image editor in C to understand what happens in detail when I edit an image with GIMP. IMAGE-->decompress-->bitmap-->edit-->bitmap-->compress-->IMAGE this is the process.

Comment: I don't understand how GIMP handles metadata... Does it transcribe them into the final image? Does it ignore them? I would like to create an editor that returns images that always have the same metadata and raw data template. For example, with GIMP if I deactivate all metadata when I export an image it creates a final image that always has those 10 fundamental metadata. Does this mean that it always adds the same metadata to the final image and ignores all the metadata of the initial image?

Comment: @andreo I don't have GIMP-specific answers for you, but there is much information about there about scripting the removal of EXIF data from image files.  For example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312754/how-to-strip-metadata-from-image-files  Also, the tool described in there is also capable of extracting and reimporting EXIF metadata.  Perhaps it might help your workflow to preserve the metadata separately and then overwrite it in the image file after all your processsing is done?  (ExifTool)

Comment: In any case, @andreo it might be a good idea to ask another question about this topic.

Comment: Yes, I actually went a bit off topic with this question...

Comment: Staying on topic, if I understand correctly, PNG being a lossless image format means that if I want to decompress a PNG image into a PPM image and then recompress the PPM image into a PNG image with the same software I should obtain two PNG files identical right?

Comment: @andreo Yes.  PNG is lossless.  So, yes, you are correct that no data fidelity is lost moving between PNG and PPM.  However, do you have a compelling need for the PPM format?  Many things can be done directly on compressed formats nowadays...

Comment: Yes yes it's all hypothetical. I'm not trying to solve any real problem, I'm just trying to better understand how image formats work. I created a small image editor that receives a jpg, png or ppm as input and allows you to decompress it into a pixel map, make some changes and then recompress it into a jpg, png or ppm image.

Comment: I wanted to understand if, for example, going from jpg to ppm to png (or from png to ppm to png) any information were lost... From what I understood, no.

Comment: Yes, you don't lose any data going from JPEG -> PPM -> PNG -> PPM.  Just don't pass through JPEG again at any point.  JPEG -> PNG -> JPEG ***will*** lose data.

Answer (score 2):

PPM has up to 65536 different values per channel (RGB) which makes it capable of representing everything that comes out of a JPEG (unless there is some type of super-JPEG around). Normal JPEGs have 256 values per channel.

None of the information in the uncompressed JPEG needs therefore to be lost when rendering the picture on a virtual PPM canvas.

PPM also stores this representation losslessly, so no degradation will happen in this process. It also stores it uncompressed, which will likely make the files huge. You could use some other lossless fileformat, like PNG to store your pictures instead. PNG compresses the image without loosing information.

Note 1: There's "true PPM" and variations. The sample values in PPM are nonlinear and some constants and a gamma transfer function is used. To not *actually* loose any information, you need to use a reader which uses the same constants and transfer function when reading the PPM file.

Note 2: A fileformat being *uncompressed* is not a guarantee for losslessness when doing the conversion from JPEG to this other format. There are uncompressed fileformats not even capable of representing everything that comes out of a JPEG, so there you would have a loss when rendering the picture on the virtual canvas. It would store it uncompressed, so no further loss would happen, but then it's already too late.

Note 3: If you have the option, store the original pictures in a lossless and compressed format instead of using JPEG. JPEG is inherently lossy so there you irreversibly loose quality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't want to use an uncompressed format to store previously-lossy-compressed data. In general I'm trying to create a small image editor in C to understand what happens in detail when I edit an image with GIMP. IMAGE-->decompress-->bitmap-->edit-->bitmap-->compress-->IMAGE this is the process. The hard part now is understanding what happens to metadata in an image editor because the bitmap doesn't preserve them.

Comment: So thanks to the fact that png is lossless if I want to decompress a PNG image into a PPM image and then recompress the PPM image into a PNG image with the same software I should obtain two PNG files identical right?

Comment: @andreo Yes, if you use a channel resolution in PPM that can cover everything that's in the PNG, the image part of the PNG should be exactly the same. It's not more expensive to use the PPM value range 0-65535 than it is to use the range 0-256, which also requires two bytes, so I'd go for the maximum value possible.

Comment: Therefore PNG and PPM represent the same raw image except that PNG is compressed and has more metadata while PPM is uncompressed and has less metadata. Right?

Comment: @andreo I'm unfortunately one of those people I mentioned in the comments above that is reluctant to keep going answering follow-up questions in comments when none of the answers to the original question has been accepted.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow, I've found out now that I have to accept an answer.

Comment: @andreo You don't _have_ to accept any answer. It's completely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

To begin, there is no such thing as "quality" that is inherent in JPEG. Some JPEG CODECs, have a "quality" setting that is just a simple means of selecting quantization tables. "Quality" settings do not have the same effect on different. Quality=90 is not necessarily the same as quality=90 in a different encoder. I've seen encoders use 1 to 5, 1 to 10, and 1 to 100 quality settings and encoders that do not use a quality setting at all.

The issue in JPEG is loss, not quality.

The loss in JPEG occurs going into JPEG and not (generally) going out of JPEG. The RGB=>YCbCR conversion can introduce loss. If used, subsampling introduces loss. The DCT can produce floating to integer conversion loss. Quantization is a big source of loss.

You can have a JPEG decoder that introduces loss but that is not strictly necessary.

1. An image starts with some uncompressed bitmap format.
2. That gets converted to a JPEG. In nearly all cases that will result in some loss.
3. Now you are converting the JPEG to PPM, that will not necessarily create additional loss.