# Image from PIL module not allowing reading and writing

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The goal of this code is to encode a 64 by 64 image in binary and store it in a txt file, and then decode and load it with another script

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('image.png')
map = img.load()
width,height = img.size
pixellist = []
index = 0

def binaryToDecimal(n):
    return int(n,2)

with open('encimg.txt','r') as f:
    content = f.read()
repeatnum = len(content)/24
for i in range(int(repeatnum)):
    red = content[0:8:1]
    content = content[8:]
    green = content[0:8:1]
    content = content[8:]
    blue = content[0:8:1]
    content = content[8:]
    pixel = [binaryToDecimal(red),binaryToDecimal(green),binaryToDecimal(blue)]
    pixellist.append(pixel)
pixellist = [i for i in pixellist if i != ['','','',]]
for column in range(width):
    for row in range(height):
        map[column,row] =tuple(pixellist[column*row])
        index += 1

img.save('newimage',format='png')
```

```
from PIL import Image

input_image = Image.open("images.png")
pixel_map = input_image.load()
width, height = input_image.size
binarylist = []
index = 0

def decimalToBinary(n):
    return bin(n).replace("0b", "")

for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        r, g, b = input_image.getpixel((i, j))
        binarylist.extend([decimalToBinary(r),decimalToBinary(g),decimalToBinary(b)])

with open('encimg.txt','w') as f:
    for item in binarylist:
        f.write(item)
        index += 1
        print(index, end = '\r')
```

I tried to try the same code but with a 16x16 image instead, which worked, but wouldn't work when I scaled it back up to 64x64.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean not working, is that any error/exception raised ?

Comment: You have assumed your image has only RGB channels, whereas in practice it may be a palette image, or may be greyscale and also may have an alpha/opacity channel, i.e. RGBA. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621

Comment: Please give more detail on what worked (16x16) and what didn'twork

Comment: What is the purpose of this, please? I mean why would you want to inefficiently save an image in a format no other software can read? It may help if you create a pure black image for testing. Then pure white. Then solid red. And so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *"reader"* code assumes 8 binary digits per colour, but your writer/encoder doesn't produce 8 binary digits per colour.

You use:

```
return bin(n).replace("0b","")
```

which will produce `0` when X=0, rather than the `00000000` you were probably expecting.

Try the following instead

```
return f'{n:08b}'
```

Just FYI, if you haven't seen such things before they are call *"f-strings"* and are described [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

Also, your loops need interchanging in the encoder, so they read:

```
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
```

---

Your whole concept is grossly inefficient, but your decoder is especially bad and will take minutes for large images because you are constantly shuffling the entire variable `content` to the left by 8 characters with:

```
content = content[8:]
```

You would be better to use indexing into the variable, rather than recreating it for every pixel, i.e.:

```
offset = 0
for i in range(int(repeatnum)):
    red   = content[offset:offset+8:1]
    green = content[offset+8:offset+16:1]
    blue  = content[offset+16:offset+24:1]
    offset += 24
    pixel = (binaryToDecimal(red),binaryToDecimal(green),binaryToDecimal(blue))
```

Also, you need to make a tuple to put in `map`.

Also, your population of `map` miscalculates the offset into your pixel list, it needs to be:

```
for column in range(width):
for row in range(height):
    this = pixellist[column+(width*row)]
    map[column,row] = this
```

---

To be sure of being able to save palette images and images with transparency in your RGB format, you should change this line:

```
input_image = Image.open("images.png")
```

to this:

```
input_image = Image.open("images.png").convert('RGB')
```

---

The whole code (as hacked to work, rather than being what I would recommend is as follows for the encoder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

input_image = Image.open("a.png").convert('RGB')
pixel_map = input_image.load()
width, height = input_image.size
binarylist = []
index = 0

def decimalToBinary(n):
    return f'{n:08b}'

for j in range(height):
    for i in range(width):
        r, g, b = input_image.getpixel((i, j))
        print(f'{r=} {g=} {b=}')
        binarylist.extend([decimalToBinary(r),decimalToBinary(g),decimalToBinary(b)])

with open('encimg.txt','w') as f:
    for item in binarylist:
        f.write(item)
        print(f'{item=}')
```

and as follows for the decoder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('a.png').convert('RGB')
map = img.load()
width,height = img.size
print(f'DEBUG: {width=} {height=}')
pixellist = []
index = 0

def binaryToDecimal(n):
    return int(n,2)

with open('encimg.txt','r') as f:
    content = f.read()
repeatnum = len(content)/24

offset = 0
for i in range(int(repeatnum)):
    red   = content[offset:offset+8:1]
    green = content[offset+8:offset+16:1]
    blue  = content[offset+16:offset+24:1]
    offset += 24
    pixel = (binaryToDecimal(red),binaryToDecimal(green),binaryToDecimal(blue))
    pixellist.append(pixel)

#pixellist = [i for i in pixellist if i != ['','','',]]
for column in range(width):
    for row in range(height):
        this = pixellist[column+(width*row)]
        map[column,row] = this
        print(f'{column=},{row=} {this=}')

img.save('result.png')
```

---

If I ***had*** to code this using lists and loops and stuff, I would probably go with something like this for the encoder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Open image and ensure in RGB mode - not palette, not alpha
input_image = Image.open("a.png").convert('RGB')

with open('encimg.txt','w') as f:
    # Get pixels via PIL generator
    for pixel in input_image.getdata():
        str = f'{pixel[0]:08b}{pixel[1]:08b}{pixel[2]:08b}'
        f.write(str)
```

and something like this for the decoder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

width, height = 640, 480
print(f'DEBUG: {width=} {height=}')

pixels = []
with open('encimg.txt','r') as f:
    while this := f.read(24):
       R = this[0:8:1]
       G = this[8:16:1]
       B = this[16:24:1]
       pixels.append((int(R,2), int(G,2), int(B,2)))

# Create new, empty output image
result = Image.new('RGB', (width,height))
# Stuff decoded data into it
result.putdata(pixels)
result.save('result.png')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I am relatively new to python and still learning how to make it more efficient

Comment: My pleasure - good luck with your project.