# PIL is corrupting my image data when reading from it using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

So I've been working on this problem for a little over a year now, off and on, and this specific problem has persisted after two complete rewrites of the entire program. The problem in questiion is that PIL will "corrupt" my data after I've imported it into python. I'm not sure if the way I'm iterating over it is causing it, but it only happens on specific PNG files, and it handles others perfectly fine. For example, this PNG
[before PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7BUf.png)
is ending up like this:
[after PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKSbr.png)
The corruption pattern is consistent with all the PNGs that become corrupted, where parts of the image get checkerboxed and some remain the same.

I've rewritten the code twice, tried to use numpy arrays instead of lists, tried different ways of iterating over the code, and nothing seems to be working. I'm fairly sure that it has something to do with the way I'm iterating over it, as saving the image from the data saves it accurately, but I have no clue what's going wrong.

Here's the entirety of the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
def encode(string):
    encoded = ""
    #Create an array of tuples with the value and the number of times it appears in a row, then stringify it
    index = 0
    while index < len(string)-1:
        count = 1
        while string[index] == string[index+1]:
            count += 1
            index += 1
            if index == len(string) - 1:
                break
        encoded += "(" + string[index] + ")" + str(count)
        index += 1

    return encoded

def decode(encoded):
    decoded = ""
    for i in range(len(encoded)):
        if encoded[i] == "(":
            color = encoded[i+1]
            index = i+2
            while encoded[index] != ")":
                color += encoded[index]
                index += 1
            multiplier = ""
            while True:
                index += 1
                if index > len(encoded) - 1 or encoded[index] == "(":
                    break
                multiplier += encoded[index]
            decoded += color * int(multiplier)
    return decoded





path = input("Path to image:")
img = Image.open(path)
img.verify()
img = Image.open(path)
#img = img.convert('RGB')
rows = int(input("Height of image:"))
pixel_size = int(img.height/rows) #Calculated by dividing the size of the image by the size given on pixilart
print(pixel_size)


data = numpy.asarray(img)



#loop through each pixel and find all RGB values, then create a dict containing all RGB values corresponding to incrementing numbers
colors = {}
#convert lists to tuples so they can be used as keys in the dict

data = [[tuple(element) for element in row] for row in data]
new_data = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    if i%pixel_size == 0:
        new_row = []
        for j in range(len(data[i])):
            if j%pixel_size == 0:
                new_row.append(data[i][j])
        new_data.append(new_row)

data = new_data

img = Image.fromarray(numpy.asarray(new_data))
img.save("test.png")


index = 0
for row in data:
    for pixel in row:
        if pixel not in colors.keys():
            colors[pixel] = str(index)
            index += 1
print(len(colors))
image = []
index = 0
"""
for row_index in range(rows):
    pixel_row = data[row_index*pixel_size]
    row = ""
    for pixel in range(int(len(pixel_row)/pixel_size)):
        row += colors[pixel_row[pixel*pixel_size]]
    row = encode(row)
    image.append(row)
    index += 1
    print(f"Finished {index}/{rows} rows.",end="\r")
"""
for row in data:
    rle = ""
    for pixel in row:
        rle += colors[pixel]
    image.append(encode(rle))

img = Image.fromarray(numpy.asarray(data))
img.save("after.png")

inverted_colors = {}
for key in colors.keys():
    inverted_colors[colors[key]] = list(key)

new_image = []
for row in image:
    decoded_row = decode(row)
    row_array = []
    for i in range(len(decoded_row)):
        row_array.append(inverted_colors[decoded_row[i]])
    new_image.append(row_array)




with open("output.txt", "w") as file:
    template = """var scene = {
    art: %s,
    palette: %s,
    rowSize: %s
};"""%(image,inverted_colors,rows)
    file.write(template)
```

EDIT: Here's the output that the program generates for this specific artwork:

https://pastebin.com/T18Nuaen

Comment: Can you check if it affects other file formats such as jpg?

Comment: Yes, it has the same corruption even when in a different file format.

Comment: Take a step back... what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to take all the colors in an image, put them into a dictionary, then using that dictionary, take all the data in an image and convert it into a dictionary containing rows of strings filled by the colors of the image represented as the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: How about showing what your starting input image and corresponding output image look like, so we can better understand and assist you?

Comment: I did, they're linked in the post.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are trying to do. You say you want to produce *"rows of strings"* as output, which sounds like text to me, but you are only showing an image - and that's wrong too but I don't know why it's wrong or how it should look.

Comment: I'm trying to take an image in, convert it into an array containing a string for each "row" of pixels in the image, then I have another piece of Javascript code that takes in that array, along with the dictionary of colors that was generated by the python code, and recreates the original image. However, the original image isn't properly being converted to the array, causing the corruption that occurs. Ideally, the two images should look exactly the same.

Comment: Why are you doing all this creating stringified rows of tuples of text and dictionaries? What's the point? What are you trying to achieve? Transmit a text file that contains an image? Why don't you base64-encode it? Are you trying to reduce the colours? Hide something? Why don't you show the Javascript? Where's the textfile you produce? Is that correct? Why is your output image larger than your input image?

Comment: 1. I'm trying to convert the image into a format that's easily copy pasted, and preferably easy to understand without decoding. Space isn't a huge concern, which is why I'm doing it this way.

2. Base64 doesn't suit my use case.

3. The JavaScript isn't part of the problem, it's working perfect right now and I can see the corruption is part of the python code generation.

4.I'll attach the generated textfile to the main post.

5.The output image is larger because it's a screenshot, while the first one is a direct upload of the image.

Comment: Perhaps a useful hint here: the 'corruption' doesn't seem to be significant. It looks like a particular color is being dropped out or interpreted as alpha (transparent) instead.  Look at the after, it's the same pic but red/brown has been replaced with transparency.  Maybe there's some parameter for `Image.fromarray()` which is needed in order to get those color values correctly interpreted...

Comment: I think it's more complex than that, because you can see that the image also becomes slightly shifted as well, if you take a look at the spikes in the upper right corner, it looks like the data from the actual array is being changed, because otherwise the entire image would be the same except for the changed color parts. I tried changing my code for converting the image to a numpy array, and the corruption persisted.

Comment: Also, I quickly wrote a small script in Python just to prove that the corruption isn't caused by the javascript code, and it had the exact same corruption. I also see what you mean, the brown parts are the only parts getting corrupted. However, I can't see why those parts in particular would be affected by my code?

Comment: If you have a new 'small script' which demonstrates the corruption, it would be great if you share that.  That would get us closer to the 'minimal reproducible example' that this question needs to have attached to it.  BTW, I tried running with your input image and the Python code you've attached so far and I did _not_ see any 'corruption'.  I recommend attaching a minimal example which has a hardcoded PNG filename and no other inputs. Something we can just run and we will immediately see your issue.

Comment: I'd suggest you divide all this code in suitably sized functions, instead of a big lump of top level code  + 2 functions, and then just write unit-tests for each of the smaller functions. You will have to think what the output of each part must be, and check if it matches or not: it will be possible to pinpoint the error source. As it is, anyone trying to answer your question would have to follow a similar procedure, but without _knowing_ which should be the output at each stage of your processing.

Comment: https://github.com/B1Fr0st/pixtoRLE, I've rewritten it to use functions, and it is now minimum example.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not yet complete, I am slowly trying to work out what you are actually trying to do. So far, I think you are trying to:

- convert your image to a palette (a.k.a index) image, by wading through lists of tuples of pixels. See [What's the difference between Palette mode and other images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621).
- decimate your image (by a factor of pixel_height=192) by wading through lists of pixels. See *"Numpy Slicing and Striding"* [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html).

I will try and convert your code to simpler, more performant methods, and if you want to adopt them and build them into your code, maybe at some point, we will replace whatever is causing the errors.

So, in general, you want to **avoid** `for` loops and lists - use built-in Pillow methods and/or vectorised Numpy routines. I think the following couple of lines replace a significant percentage of your code and reduce the processing time enormously.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image_height = 192

# Load image, find unique colours and convert to palette image
im = Image.open('art.png').convert('P')

# Convert to Numpy array of shape=(1152,1152) containing palette indices
na = np.array(im)

# Decimate image by factor of im.height/image_height (192)
factor = int(im.height / image_height)
di = na[::factor, ::factor]
```

The array `di` now has shape (192,192) and contains the indices into your palette and looks like this:

```
array([[8, 8, 8, ..., 6, 6, 6],
       [8, 8, 8, ..., 6, 6, 6],
       [8, 8, 8, ..., 6, 6, 6],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 2, 4, 4],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 4, 4, 4],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 4, 4, 4]], dtype=uint8)
```

Your palette of colours can be obtained with `getpalette()` and I am just reshaping it so it looks like rows of RGB colours:

```
palette = np.reshape(im.getpalette(),(-1,3))
```

It looks like this with 12 RGB entries:

```
array([[226, 207, 180],    <-- RGB values for index 0
       [ 92, 139, 147],    <-- RGB values for index 1
       [217, 172, 139],
       [224, 200, 114],
       [212, 128,  77],
       [ 93, 114, 117],
       [ 62, 105,  88],
       [176,  58,  72],
       [177, 165, 141],
       [ 98,  76,  60],
       [ 36,  61,  92],
       [ 43,  40,  33],
```

---

As regards *"Run Length Encoding"* the data, you could use a function like this:

```
def rle(data):
    
    # Start off with run of length 1 of first element 
    run = [data[0], 1]

    # Iterate through rest of data
    for elem in data[1:]:
        if elem != run[-2]: 
            # New element, start new run
            run += [elem, 1]
        else:
            # Another sample of existing element
            run[-1] += 1
    print(run)
```

Then you can iterate over the rows of your decimated image `di` with:

```
encoded = [rle(row) for row in di]
```

---

I'll leave you to join all the pieces and format the output however you wish.

Comment: Note that I created an all white and an all black test image and your outputs looked roughly reasonable. However, I created a white-to-black gradient image (white at the top, black at the bottom) and your palette came out all white, so I think you are iterated across the top row instead of down the side. Are you aware that Numpy's first index is the row and its second index is the column - i.e. reversed relative to what you might expect? The top-right pixel is at `im[0,width-1]`

Comment: So I rewrote the code to utilize the snippets that you gave me (thank you very much for the help by the way), and now the corruption pattern is different on the image. So, progress? I uploaded it to the git repository that I previously posted, along with the code I wrote.